# How set fields Type witch is depends on type of fields in this type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How make right something like this type?

```
    type SelectFieldProps = {
      // isMulti: boolean;
      // selectedOption: SelectFieldProps['isMulti'] extends true ? SelectOption[] : SelectOption;
    } & (
      | { isMulti: true; selectedOption: SelectOption[] }
      | { isMulti: false; selectedOption: SelectOption }
    );
```

It needs for using props witch are have different formats in ReactJS:

```js
            {isMulti &&
              selectedOption.slice(0, 2).map((opt) => (
                <div className={b('value', ['multi'])} key={opt.value.toString()}>
                  {opt?.label}
                </div>
              ))}
            {
              !isMulti && (
                <div className={b('value', ['multi'])}>
                  {selectedOption?.label}
                </div>                
              )
            }
```

Comment: Can you share on how this type would be used?

Comment: Your type looks correct to me.